# Cant Receive Nest Mongo Database JSON Array in Angular Component

Tags: angular, mongodb, http, observable, nest

I am doing a test run from my Nest backend connected to MongoDB/Mongoose, where everything is working between Nest and MongoDB Cloud using Postman. I am just clicking a button in an attempt to receive the data in Angular and set to a variable.

However, when I try to bring the data to the frontend to accept the data and assign to a variable and ultimately send the data to NGXS state I cannot read(log) the data as an object, I am only able to display the data in the html using an async pipe, which isn't the end goal, just where Ive gotten so far with tutorials.

In my service I call the basic login data:

```
  getDisplay() {
    let response = this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/');
    return response;
   }
```

Then in the nav component where I have the button(that triggers dbTest). The JSON should return as an array of one of my models so UserRegister[], but I have been applying that in places as well as trying to subscribe in different places but none seem to work out. I thought restricting the observable dbData$ to receive the type UserRegister and enacting async await or subscribe would work and force it to a manipulable object to send to state would work, but no luck.

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
      dbData$: Observable<any> | undefined;  

      dbTest() {
          this.dbData$ = this.authService.getDisplay();
          console.log('after');
          console.log(this.dbData$);
      }}
```

But in the html I actually will receive the data to display, because of async pipe I would assume.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dbData$ | async">
   <div>{{ item.username }}</div>
   <div>{{ item.email }}</div>
</div>
```

[Display in html actually showing values from MongoDB through Nest, It works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgmUn.png)

Also, this is the console showing the log of the value as some 'LiftedSource'? which im not seeing much about in search as well as...the http response with the actual values I would like to push to state(obviously I wouldn't send password to state, but this a basic starter to get to the real data I want to send to state)

[Console After button click activating dbTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV9wV.png)

Comment: You can just subscribe to the observable? this.dbData$.subscribe ((data:any) => { console.log(data)})

Comment: Awesome! That did it! Thank you!

json data is received in component after click with

  dbTest() {
    this.dbData$ = this.authService.getDisplay();
    this.dbData$.subscribe((data:any)=> {console.log(data)})
    console.log('after');
    console.log(this.dbData$);
  }

Answer (score 0):

MikeOne Answered above. Thank you!

All I had to do was subscribe to dbData$ after the expression going to the authService.

I think I had tried chaining the subscribe after getDisplay() and it was not accepting it

updated function in the component is

```
  dbTest() {
     this.dbData$ = this.authService.getDisplay();
     this.dbData$.subscribe((data:any)=> {console.log(data)})
     console.log('after');
     console.log(this.dbData$);
     }
```